# Regular expression for complex url java script

Tags: javascript, regex

i have URL like http://www.moevenpick-hotels.com/en/pub/hotels_resorts/worldmap/tala_bay_aqaba/welcome.cfm

I want to make regular expression for that ....... that regex should accept all type of symbol in between words  include dot .... i mean it should be proper url

above url is the best example for that ..

Please tell me how to resolve

Comment: You want to sanitize URLs, right? But there's more than just not allowing dots in this.

Comment: This regular expression matches your criteria: `/[^.]*/`

Comment: please give me full regex .......for url http://www.moevenpick-hotels.com/en/pub/hotels_resorts/worldmap/tala_bay_aqaba/welcome.cfm

i am using right now 

var regExpForWebsite = "^(http://)?(www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|co.uk|com.au|gov|in|fr|co.in|gov.in|ac|de|uk.com|us.com|eu.com)$";

i know it does not work

Comment: There's no way your criteria are well defined. `/[^.]*/` matches anything that doesn't contain a dot.

Comment: ... and what you want will not allow most URLs because you won't have a domain without dot in the WWW. @Asad

Comment: Now after your edit this is what you want: `/.*/`

Comment: sorry i have been edited my question ...... 

stright forward question .....i want regular expression in javascript for url : 

http://www.moevenpick-hotels.com/en/pub/hotels_resorts/worldmap/tala_bay_aqaba/welcome.cfm

I hope its clear ...sorry for confusion

Comment: @user870686 Ah I see, so you want this regex: `/http:\/\/www\.moevenpick-hotels\.com\/en\/pub\/hotels_resorts\/worldmap\/tala_bay_aqaba\/welcome\.cfm/`

Comment: @asad right .... and this is only example url i am using ......i have one registration form in which user can insert his url so it can be any type of url ....that is only example ..

Comment: remove the $ at the end of your regex. your current regex rejects all urls that include a filepath

Comment: @teddybeard no its not working ....... and even if i remove $ at the end what about - (hyphen)  that added in moevenpick-hotels ....

right now i am using regex 

^(http://)?(www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|co.uk|com.au|gov|in|f‌​r|co.in|gov.in|ac|de|uk.com|us.com|eu.com)$

can you please edit above and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match valid hostnames, however, it does not check the filepath:

```
var regExpForWebsite = /^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|co.uk|com.au|gov|in|f‌r|co.in|gov.in|ac|de|uk.com|us.com|eu.com)/;
regExpForWebsite.test('http://www.moevenpick-hotels.com/en/pub/hotels_resorts/worldmap/tala_bay_aqaba/welcome.cfm');

==>true
```